# Laravel BelongsToMany relationship with WhereHas condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have some relationship in my DB:

```
public function managers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'manager_location', 'location_id', 'manager_id')
}
```

This relation works well - return all users which were synced with some location.
I'm using `spatie/laravel-permissions` and my users have different roles. When I'm trying to return users with some role (add the `whereHas` to the relation) it continues to returns all records:

```
public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'manager_location', 'location_id', 'manager_id')->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
            $q->where('name', '=','manager');
        });
    }
```

Where I went wrong?

P.S.
Mysql log query:

```
select * from `users` inner join `manager_location` on `users`.`id` = `manager_location`.`manager_id` where `manager_location`.`location_id` is null and exists (select * from `roles` inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `users`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`model_id` and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = ? and `name` = ?)
```

Dump of QueryBuilder: https://pastebin.com/j6ik35mK

Comment: Try adding [`->dd()`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_dd) to your query builder to view the generated query. Can you post this here?

Comment: Just updated my first message. Thanks.